date is not showing in SfCalendar on onViewChanged callback
I am using SfCalendar in my Flutter application.When i change the current view of calendar, that is view swiped to previous /next view, I am not getting the details.
Here is my code
   SfCalendar(
                controller: _calendarController,
                initialSelectedDate: DateTime.now(),
                view: CalendarView.schedule,
                dataSource: MeetingDataSource(_getMeetingSource()),
                onViewChanged: (ViewChangedDetails details) {
                  print('here $details');
                  // List<DateTime> dates = details.visibleDates;
                },
                scheduleViewSettings: const ScheduleViewSettings(
                    hideEmptyScheduleWeek: true,
                    weekHeaderSettings: WeekHeaderSettings(height: 0),
                    monthHeaderSettings: MonthHeaderSettings(
                      monthFormat: 'MMMM, yyyy',
                      height: 0,
                      textAlign: TextAlign.left,
                    ),
                    appointmentTextStyle:
                        TextStyle(fontSize: 12, fontWeight: FontWeight.w500)),
                showDatePickerButton: true,
              ),

it's not printing the details. I have added _calendarController, but still it's not working.

Be aware that the SyncFusion products in the Dart/Flutter pub are not open source.  They are released under a commercial license that may subject you or your organization to a financial liability, and will affect downstream re-users of your code.
